# How can I fully disable italics with the Kanagawa theme in Neovim?

Tags: lua, neovim, neovim-plugin

I really like the Kanagawa theme and want to use it in my Neovim editor. However I do not like italicized words in my code and I cannot figure out how to fully disable italics. I have this config now based on the [README](https://github.com/rebelot/kanagawa.nvim?tab=readme-ov-file#configuration):

```lua
require("kanagawa").setup({
  commentStyle = { italic = false },
  keywordStyle = { italic = false },
})
```

And this disables *most* italics in the theme, however keywords like `self` in Rust or `this` in Java/Javascript are still showing italicized.

I've tried looking for answers in the repo and elsewhere, but haven't found a solution to this.

Answer (score 3):

After digging through the source code, I found that the option `"@variable.builtin"` is [hardcoded](https://github.com/rebelot/kanagawa.nvim/blob/bfa818c7bf6259152f1d89cf9fbfba3554c93695/lua/kanagawa/highlights/treesitter.lua#L13) to `italic = true`. Using the overrides configuration, this particular option can be given an `italic = false` option:

```lua
require("kanagawa").setup({
  commentStyle = { italic = false },
  keywordStyle = { italic = false },
  overrides = function()
    return {
      ["@variable.builtin"] = { italic = false },
    }
  end
})
```

I opened [this issue](https://github.com/rebelot/kanagawa.nvim/issues/216) in the repo with a suggested enhancement to make this configuration more obvious.